# Is it possible to create a branch when having uncommitted changes?

Tags: mercurial

In Mercurial repo:

1) I've checked out (updated) from `default`

2) I've edited something

3) I've realized I need a branch to experiment with my edits

4) When I try to create a branch Mercurial claims I have uncommitted changes

If I don't get mistaken, in `git` allows you to `checkout -b` in such situation. I need to create a branch and commit my changes there.

**UPDATE**

It turned out that hg is as smart as git, and ALLOWS creating branches when having uncommitted changes. So, the problem on step 4 had no relation to hg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works just fine for me:

```
ry4an@four:~$ hg init dan
ry4an@four:~$ cd dan
ry4an@four:~/dan$ echo text > afile
ry4an@four:~/dan$ hg commit -Am added
adding afile
ry4an@four:~/dan$ echo more >> afile
ry4an@four:~/dan$ hg branch newbranch
marked working directory as branch newbranch
(branches are permanent and global, did you want a bookmark?)
ry4an@four:~/dan$ hg commit -m another
ry4an@four:~/dan$ hg log
changeset:   1:84b54b473852
branch:      newbranch
tag:         tip
user:        Ry4an Brase <ry4an-hg@ry4an.org>
date:        Wed Dec 04 11:36:52 2013 -0500
summary:     another

changeset:   0:b07d96580927
user:        Ry4an Brase <ry4an-hg@ry4an.org>
date:        Wed Dec 04 11:36:13 2013 -0500
summary:     added
```

When I ran `hg branch newbranch` nothing was actually created.  The `hg branch` command just tells Mercurial what branch the **next** commit should be on, and indeed when I did that commit the log shows it was on `newbranch`.  I had uncommitted changes when I did the `hg branch` line and there was no warning or error saying I couldn't do it -- how, specifically, are you trying to create that branch?

Comment: Your example works for me. I have a feeling the reason is pre-commit hooks attached to mercurial. Need to make a double check to be quite sure, will do this tomorrow

Comment: Cool a precommit hook won't run on the 'hg branch ..' command (it's not committing anything) but it could certainly stop a subsequent commit.

Comment: Yeah, that were hooks